# ограничения на переход к методам контроллера ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Можно ли как ограничить, доступ к методам контроллера. Например можно ли установить так, что вызвать метод контроллера можно, только из другого контроллера?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*А создавать экземпляр этого контроллера с ценным методом Вы собираетесь сами?*

Перенесите код в класс, который не является контроллером, и вызывайте его методы откуда хотите.

Comment: я просто имел ввиду, что например после авторизации (ввод логина и пароля), переход ко второму пункту входа. И чтобы на этот пункт нельзя было попасть не пройдя 1.

Comment: @Идентикон То, что Вы описываете, это стандартное поведение ASP.NET authentication.